# How to set figure size in Matlab without setting its position?

Tags: matlab, plot

In Python I can pass size to `figure` directive:

```
figure(figsize=(8,6))
```

In Matlab I don't see this capability. I have complex advises like

```
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'manual');
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches');
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [2 1 4 2]);
```

which includes both setting size and position.

How to set only size in most simply way in Matlab?

Comment: Several questions: 1) Which MATLAB version are you using? 2) What do you hope to achieve exactly that requires not changing the figure `Position`? Are you trying to export the figure in some higher resolution? Please also explain your motivation.

Comment: The code you've posted modifies the size and the positoin of the figure, but it only has effect when you either print or save the figure. Do you want it or (and) do you want to resize the "window" as it is shown on the screen?

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
set(gcf, 'Position', get(gcf,'Position').*[1 1 0 0] + [0 0 newWidth newHeight]);
```

If your MATLAB is R2014b or newer, you could also do:

```
hF = gcf;
hF.Position(3:4) = [newWidth newHeight];
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no possibility to set only the size but you can get the default position/size and use it as a workaround. To do so just write something like:

```
figPos = get(0,'defaultfigureposition');
width = 400;
height = 400;
figure('Position', [figPos(1), figPos(2), width, height]);
```

This will set the size only while initializing the figure. For figures already initialized, use the handle element `gcf` of the figure:

```
set(gcf, 'Position', [values])
```

If you want to set that size as default, use `set` to the property `'defaultfigureposition'`:

```
set(0, 'defaultfigureposition', [values]);
```